# How to use Kmodes in R (Categorical data clustering)

Tags: r, algorithm, csv, data-visualization, k-means

I want to cluster my categorical data from a csv file. I want to use kmodes algorithm

CSV File example(50 row from my data):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Z58iD3By5wUzduOXUwUDh1OVU/view?usp=sharing

```
library(klaR)
setwd("D:/Skripsi/TMC Polda Metro Jaya 2014-2016/----DATA FIX CLEAR 2014-
2016/kmodes")
data.to.cluster <- read.csv('DATA KECELAKAAN TWITTER 2014 -2016 FIX -2(untuk k-
means) - versi 3.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ';')
cluster.results <- kmodes(data.to.cluster[,2:5], 3, iter.max = 10, weighted = FALSE)
```

I cant get a result from this code.

To be honest I'm new to data-visualization so how can I get a result from kmodes in R/visualize it?
Is there another good algorithm for categorical data especially in R with relevant documentation?

Comment: Have you checked the structure of `data.to.cluster` after you read your data into R? From the sample provided, it seems like the file uses semicolon as the separator, but the sep defined in `read.csv` is the comma. Perhaps the error is due to the incorrect formatting in the dataset.

Comment: neither is working for me. i tried semicolon still cant cluster it. i still confuse how r read csv and display it

Comment: Check the results of `str(data.to.cluster)`. Does your dataset even have 5 or more columns? If not, rerun your previous line for `read.csv()` with `sep = ";"` instead.

Comment: str(data.to.cluster <- read.csv('DATA KECELAKAAN TWITTER 2014 -2016 FIX -2(u$
'data.frame':   49 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Number.JKM.JKMo.JKB.JKT.WD.WP.WS.Wso.WM: Factor w/ 49 levels "1;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0",..: 1 12 23 34 45 46 47 48 49 2 ...

Comment: that's the result when i use command str

Comment: ah yeah semicolon data is more clean

Comment: do u know how to see the result from kmodes/visualize it? because when i use semicolon sep , the program doesnt give me anything/just blank no error and no result

Comment: type `cluster.results` into the console. you should see the output there.

Comment: owh i see thx ! now i will try to search how to visualize it._.